# Who should be allowed to create a new tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, privileges

There is a recent [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143082/if-a-conjecture-is-proved-then-is-it-solved-proved) on MO that includes two new tags: Beer and Bet!  The problems of these two tags aside, I don't think it is a good practice to add new tags unless it is absolutely necessary. Is it possible to add a feature in which a number of MOers (for example, three users) should agree with the introduction of a new tag before its use?

Answer (score 14):

Such a system would be technically impossible since we can't delay posting a question until tags have been approved. However, this is not a serious problem:

- Only users with at least 300 points can create new tags.
- Users are quick to delete inappropriate tags from posts.
- Unused tags get purged in 24 hours; single use tags get deleted after 6 months.
- Moderators and some users regularly check [newly created tags](https://mathoverflow.net/tags?tab=new) for problematic cases.

There is no need for additional measures.

Comment: I do not think it is technically impossible. One could have something like a pending-tag which can be used right away but if not approved "self-destructs" after some fixed time. (One would just need to ensure there must be a stable tag, not only pending ones, on each question to avoid many untagged questions.) But I agreee it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: @quid That's worse than the current system. It's much better to steer someone into using [tag:lo.logic]+[tag:forcing] rather than having [tag:lo.logic]+[tag:mathias-forcing] degenerate into [tag:lo.logic] alone because [tag:mathias-forcing] was deemed too specific by someone.

Comment: Also infrequently used tags with only 1 (or 2?) questions get cleaned up every year(?) if I remember correctly.

Comment: Well, if one wants to develop on the idea, one could have the approval/disaproval process contain an option to suggest merge/synonym, so that this steering would be built-in. @Kaveh yes this exists, it is single used tags and after 6 months.

Comment: A minor clarification of one of the bullet points. A tag used only on one question is removed (after a certain time period) [unless the tag-wiki was created for the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki).